# Matlab-style Find in Mathematica? Value list and Boolean List, how to select values according to the boolean list?

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation, filtering

I want to select elements with the true value (Indices list) in the corresponding point to the value list (MCS). Is there anything like Matlab-style Find to get the indices of true values in the boolean list and then use it like `MCS[[indicesNumbers]]`?

[image]

Comment: Check for `Pick` on the docs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Rojo suggested, Pick works -- yet there may be other solutions.

[image]

Comment: +1 I doubt any solution will be better than this built-in, since it is quite straightforward. The third argument defaults to `True` so you ca do without it

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use `Position`. Here's the data vector and logical vector and a way to find the indices where `True` occurs:

```
q = {True, False, False, True, False, True};
data = Range[6] + 5;
ind=Position[Boole[q], 1]
{{1},{4},{6}}
```

The information can then be extracted from the `data` vector using

```
Extract[data, ind]
{6, 9, 11}
```

Or you can bypass using `Extract` by direct indexing:

```
data[[Flatten[ind]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
Pick[MCS, Indices]
```

is the best answer (as discussed).

Just for variety:

```
Extract[MCS, Position[Indices, True]]

Cases[Thread[{MCS, Indices}], {x_, True} :> x]
```

and not particularly elegant:

```
Reap[Sow @@@ Thread[{MCS, Indices}], True, #2 &][[2, 1]]
```